# Give a select the same outline styling as an input

Tags: html, css

My requirement is for select elements to have sharp edges like I have done with the mark up and css in the code.

The problem is I want the selects to have the same styling as the inputs when they have focus.

The inputs have a border and an outline.

I can sort of get the same effect with the select but the border is rounded when they have focus as I cannot use outline twice.

Is there a way round this?

```css
div {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: 1px solid #727272;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0065bd;
  outline: 3px solid #ffbf47;
  outline-offset: 0;
}

select {
  outline: 1px solid #727272;
}

select:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0065bd;
  outline: 3px solid #ffbf47;
  outline-offset: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div>
  <select>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not getting any rounding in firefox or chrome. Which browser?

Comment: chrome, the select is rounded, the border is not

Comment: sorry, i mean when it has focus

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select {     
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Comment: that is great but it hides the arrow

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw, not getting rounding in Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit).

[image]